# Convert String to hex and send via serial in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert the string `400AM49L01` to a hexadecimal form (and then into bytes) `b'x\34\x30\x30\x41\x4d\x34\x39\x4c\x30'`, so I can write it with `pySerial`.
I already tried to convert the elements of a list, which contains the single hexadecimals like `0x31` (equals `4`), into bytes, but this will result in `b'400AM49L01'`.

```
device = '400AM49L01'
device = device.encode()
device = bytes(device)
device = str(binascii.hexlify(device), 'ascii')
code = '0x'
text = []
count = 0
for i in device:
    if count % 2 == 0 and count != 0:
        text.append(code)
        code = '0x'
        count = 0
    code += i
    count += 1
text.append((code))
result = bytes([int(x, 0) for x in text])
```

Really looking forward for your help!

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome to SOF! Questions in SOF should have,
1. what you're trying to achieve?
2. what is the problem you're facing?
3. what is the research effort from your end to resolve the issue?
4. Share sample code and/or error details.

@ManuMM Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give the result you expecting.

```py
my_str = '400AM49L01'

"".join(hex(ord(c)) for c in my_str).encode()

# Output
# '0x340x300x300x410x4d0x340x390x4c0x300x31'
```

What is it doing ?

1. In order to convert a string to hex, you need to convert each character to the integer value from the ascii table using `ord()`.
2. Convert each int value to hex using the function `hex()`.
3. Concatenate all hex value generated using `join()`.
4. Encode the str to bytes using `.encode()`.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks! Is there any chance to format the bytes in a way that there is a backsash in front of the `x` instead of the `0`? It should be like this: `b'\x02\x02\x0D\x53\x01\x34\x30\x30\x41\x4d\x34\x39\x4c\x30\x31\x00'`